# Isolating / sandboxing untrusted code in .NET appdomain

Tags: .net, security, appdomain, sandbox

I am trying to isolate code in an Appdomain with a low permission set.
However, i would like to expose some specific functionality to be provided through an interface (which is implemented in an assembly i do trust).

When creating the appdomain i pass the StrongName for the TrustedAssembly as the 5th argument (params StrongName[] fulltrustAssemblies).

However, wheen the UntrustedAssembly calls into the TrustedAssembly, i still get a security exception when accessing the internet.

TrustedAssembly allows for PartiallyTrustedCallers.

Below, the code i use to create the sandbox and both assemblies.
not sure what i'm missing here. I am not a security expert and i know a lot has changed in .NET 4.0.

thanks in advance!

Olaf

**Creating the AppDomain**

```
//set up permisssion set for 'internet' zone.
Evidence ev = new Evidence();
ev.AddHostEvidence(new Zone(SecurityZone.Internet));
PermissionSet internetPS = SecurityManager.GetStandardSandbox(ev);

//get SN for 'TrustedAssembly'.
var trustedAssemblySN = typeof(IAgent).Assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();

//create appdomain
AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup { ApplicationBase = @"C:\path\to\UntrustedAssembly\bin\Debug\" };
var appdomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("sandbox", null, setup, internetPS, trustedAssemblySN);

var agent = (IAgent)appdomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("UntrustedAssembly", "UntrustedAssembly.Agent");
var context = (IContext)appdomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("TrustedAssembly", "TrustedAssembly.Context");
agent.Run(context);
```

**Trusted Assembly**

```
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]

namespace TrustedAssembly
{
    public interface IAgent
    {
        void Run(IContext context);
    }

    public interface IContext
    {
        Stream DownloadStream(Uri resource);
    }

    public class Context : MarshalByRefObject, IContext
    {
        public Stream DownloadStream(Uri resource)
        {
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(resource);
            //i would have expected this to succeed.

            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            return resp.GetResponseStream();
        }
    }
}
```

**Untrusted Assembly**

```
namespace UntrustedAssembly
{
    public class Agent : MarshalByRefObject, TrustedAssembly.IAgent
    {
        public void Run(TrustedAssembly.IContext context)
        {
            var stream = context.DownloadStream(new Uri("http://google.com"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think i got it.

Had to add the following steps:

 1. Decorate any method that requires additional trust with the
        [SecuritySafeCritical] attribute 
 2. Assert (& Revert) specific methods within
        the scope of these methods.